# Javascript / Jquery - Extract the id from a ChildElement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a pretty new to Jquery so I can't figured out why that is not working.

I'm trying to extract the id from a ChildElement.

Html:

```
<div class="merchant_working_hours_close_time">
  <select id="merchant_working_hours_attributes_1476029504945_close_time">
    <option value="">close</option>
    <option value="00:00:00">0h00</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">0h30</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">1h00</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">1h30</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">2h00</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">2h30</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">3h00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The Javascript

```
var close_time_id = document.getElementsByClassName("merchant_working_hours_close_time").firstElementChild.attr('id');
$('.variable').html(close_time_id);
```

What i'm doing wrong to return the "merchant_working_hours_attributes_1476029504945_close_time" id from select tag?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should be using jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery selectors and the .children() property and make sure you enclose it in a document ready. Note that I am triggering the function off a click (you might want to do it off a change or other action) and also I am console.logging it for display purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.merchant_working_hours_close_time').click(function(){
var close_time_id =$(this).children(0).attr('id');
console.log(close_time_id); //gives merchant_working_hours_attributes_1476029504945_close_time
$('.variable').text('The id of the child element is: ' + close_time_id);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="merchant_working_hours_close_time">
  <select id="merchant_working_hours_attributes_1476029504945_close_time">
    <option value="">close</option>
    <option value="00:00:00">0h00</option>
    <option value="00:30:00">0h30</option>
    <option value="01:00:00">1h00</option>
    <option value="01:30:00">1h30</option>
    <option value="02:00:00">2h00</option>
    <option value="02:30:00">2h30</option>
    <option value="03:00:00">3h00</option>
  </select>
 <span class='variable'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use the tag as selector when it's known . Since almost all jQuery getters  return the first it really isn't needed to filter for first

```
$(".merchant_working_hours_close_time > select").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's farly simple. `document.getElementsByClassName` will return a live NodeList of elements. To pick the first, add a `[0]` after it.

```
var close_time_id = document.getElementsByClassName("merchant_working_hours_close_time")[0].firstElementChild.getAttribute("id");
```

or, as David Thomas suggested:

```
var close_time_id = document.querySelector('.merchant_working_hours_close_time > :first-child').id;
```

or in **jQuery**:

```
var close_time_id = $(".merchant_working_hours_close_time").children().first().attr("id");
```

or:

```
var close_time_id = $(".merchant_working_hours_close_time > :first-child").attr("id");
```

Comment: Might I suggest, to develop your answer, that you add also: `document.querySelector('.merchant_working_hours_close_time > :first-child')` as an alternative? Rather than competing with you I'd prefer one answer to be as complete as possible :)

Comment: Missing `.` at jQuery selector

Comment: Still missing `.` at jQuery selector

Comment: @guest271314 uh, sorry. Failed^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct descendants `>` selector, `:first`, `.attr()` with parameter `"id"`

```
var close_time_id = $(".merchant_working_hours_close_time > :first").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is tested and is working but used other reference.**

```js
//All tested => jquery required
var close_time_id = $(".mother").children()[0].id;
$('.variable').html(close_time_id);
console.log(close_time_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mother">
  <a href="#" id="first_child">11111111111111111</a>
  <a href="#" id="second_child">222222222222222222222</a>
  <a href="#" id="last_child">33333333333333333</a>
</div>
```